# I can not restart Apache

Tags: apache2

When I restart my apache server using the command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I get the following error:

```
* Restarting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.16.30.50 for ServerName 
... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.16.30.50 for ServerName
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the message is more like a warning than an error. 
Is "ServerName" defined in your config?

The sample httpd.conf has this doc

// ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself. This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify it explicitly to prevent problems during startup. If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.

ServerName localhost:80